# Why CMD ["npm", "start"] doesnt work in Dockerfile?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, heroku

I have a Dockerfile, that includes client (angular app), server and nginx. Angular static files are served with nginx. Server is used as API for requests. Here is Dockerfile:

```
FROM node AS compile-image

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

WORKDIR /app/client

COPY ./client/package*.json ./

RUN npm install 
RUN npm build --prod

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENV NODE_ENV=production

CMD ["npm", "start"]

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY /client/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=compile-image app/client/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

If I remove last 4 lines `CMD ["npm", "start"]` is working when I run the container. But with those last 4 lines this CMD doesn't launch the server (but nginx serves static files of front).
Are there any ways to make this CMD work without splitting Dockerfile into 2-3 other Dockerfiles?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the command in shell form.

`CMD npm start`

I think maybe it is interpreting "npm" and "start" as parameters.

My other thought is that you should just split this into two Dockerfiles and spin up two separate images.

Have one container spinning up your server, and have another serving up your static files with nginx.

Then you can just create a build script that builds both images if you want to avoid having to use two separate commands every time you want to start your app.

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to run the image, you want to start the container with nginx as the base host. 
Try doing this:

1. Remove this line `CMD ["npm", "start"]`.
2. `docker build .`.
3. `docker run -p "Port you want to use externally:Port in the default.conf file" -it docker_image_id`
4. Go to localhost:PORT

The reason being, you dont want to start the first step of build process, rather you want to build up a docker that creates a LB instance, and you use the nginx (LB) instance to run your website.

Comment: But what about my Express server? It isn't going to launch this way.

Comment: COPY --from=compile-image app/client/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
Command, copies your build directory from /client/dist to /usr/share/nginx/html
nginx looks into this folder and serves whatever needs to be served.

So you don't need CMD npm start, nginx will take care of starting your Express server